# insertAtTail is not adding node in linkedlist

Tags: c, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list

I am a newbie in the data structure. I am creating a linked list program. I have created the program. But don't understand why insertAtTail is not adding the node to linked list.

```c
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head=NULL;

int main( void ) {
    insertAtHead(3);
    insertAtHead(4);
    insertAtHead(5);
    insertAtHead(8);
    insertAtTail(2);
    display();

    return 0;
}

void insertAtHead( int data ){
    struct node *newNode;

    newNode = (struct node *)malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if( head == NULL ){
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
}

void insertAtTail(int data){
    struct node *newNode, *temp;

    newNode = (struct node *)malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if( head == NULL){
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        temp = head;
        while ( temp != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp = newNode;
    }

}

void display(){
    struct node *temp;

    temp = head;
    while ( temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");   
}
```

Expect the output: 8 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> NULL

Actual Output: 8 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> NULL

Comment: Aren't you supposed to change the temp->next for the last node to point to your node...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `temp` is a local variable of the function that occupies a different memory then the nodes of the list.

After this loop

```
    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
```

the variable `temp` is set to NULL. Then in this statement

```
    temp = newNode;
```

you are changing the memory occupied by the variable itself. Nodes of the list were not changed.

Change the loop the following way

```
    temp = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp->next = newNode;
```

Also pay attention two that all functions that are used in main shall be declared before their usage.

For example

```
void insertAtHead( int data );

//...

int main( void )
{
    //...
}
```

Also it is not a good idea that the functions deal with a global variable `head`. You should rewrite the functions such a way that a head to a list would be passed as an argument to the functions.

For example in this case the function `insertAtHead` can be defined the folloing way

```
int insertAtHead( struct node **head, int data )
{
    struct node *newNode = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );

    int success = newNode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
       newNode->data = data;
       newNode->next = *head;
       *head = newNode;
    }

    return success;
}
```

As result in one program you can have several lists by declaring locally in main their heads.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int insertAtHead( struct node **head, int data )
{
    struct node *newNode = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );

    int success = newNode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
       newNode->data = data;
       newNode->next = *head;
       *head = newNode;
    }

    return success;
}

int insertAtTail( struct node **head, int data )
{
    struct node *newNode = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
    int success = newNode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = newNode;
    }

    return success;
}

void display( struct node *head )
{
    for ( struct node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf("%d -> ", current->data);
    }

    puts( "NULL" );   
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    insertAtHead( &head, 3 );
    insertAtHead( &head, 4 );
    insertAtHead( &head, 5 );
    insertAtHead( &head, 8 );
    insertAtTail( &head, 2 );

    display( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
8 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
temp = head;
while ( temp != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
}
temp = newNode;
```

Reassigning `temp` here will do nothing. Instead, check if `temp->next` is null and use that:

```
temp = head;
while (temp->next != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
}
temp->next = newNode;
```

This way, you're still altering `head`, rather than `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
while (temp != NULL)  
  temp = temp->next;
}

temp = newNode;
```

to this:

```
while (temp->next != NULL) {
  temp = temp->next;
}
temp->next = newNode;
```

since what you want to do is to go the **old last node**, and after doing do, specify that the next to the old **last node**, i.e. the *new* last node is the `newNode`.

<kbd>[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/S0PnHyx2WVzvS9be)</kbd> (Notice how I moved the definitions of your methods before the main method, so that it can compile - alternatively, you could declare the prototypes before main, and still leave the definitions as you have them now).

PS: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No.